# Interface or type for symbol type of JavaScript in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some values of symbol type in javascript and I need to convert it into typescript.

```
// Object values in Javascript
const size = {
   Large: Symbol('large'),
   Medium: Symbol('medium')
}
```

What is the best way to convert it into typescript?

Comment: What do you mean "best way"? The code you *currently show* is valid TypeScript code and the type is inferred correctly. Unless you want the type to be different than the inferred one, I am not sure why you'd change this at all.

Comment: is it a typescript code of `any` type for size contant?

Comment: Why it is a valid typescript code? Any reason would be help me a lot to understand

Comment: Any valid JavaScript code is also valid TypeScript code. Some compiler options will reject certain things, however the code you show here is fine. When you don't specify a type for a variable, it's automatically inferred from what you've assigned to it. If you have `let x = 42` then `x` would be a number, if you have `ley y = "hello"` then `y` would be a string. In your case, the inferred type is `{ Large: symbol; Medium: symbol; }`. [See here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCWAvApjAvDA3gWAFAwIBkBDAJwHNkAuGAZQE8BbAIxABsAKAcjbMq4CUAGjwEYAWWQATeAFdGNBi3bdG0uY0F4AvkA)

Comment: It makes me understand now. Could you provide me some resources to learn typescript apart from official documentation? I would also look into official documentation though.

Comment: The [official handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) is pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you ?

```
interface Size {

    LargeSize: symbol,
    MediumSize: symbol

}

const size:Size = {
   LargeSize: Symbol('large'),
   MediumSize: Symbol('medium')
}
```

Comment: Can I change the name in Size interface? like largeSize or whatever instead of Large

Comment: Yes you can , but the object property must have same name as interface property
I am going to edit , the answer to show

Comment: This is explicit typing.